# get a 3-column list of file names in the present working directory Linux command line

Tags: linux, terminal, linux-mint

get a 3-column list of file names in the present working directory Linux command line

I know how to get on column its like `ls -3`  but when i tried to get 3 column its not working is it possible to get 3 column ?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, ls doesn't support this . Your `ls` output will have to be piped. Data can be sorted using programmes like `sed` or `cut` if you know what your delimiter is. When it comes to column spacing, the most common delimiter is a tab.

you can also use `ls -wn` replace n with integer according to your screen size,
this pretty much work nice according to your terminal size and also u can grab terminal size using `stty size` and calculate your value according to your desired output.

```
$ stty size | cut -d" " -f1   #height
 36  #sample_output

$ stty size | cut -d" " -f2   #width
 78  #sample_output

$ ls -w90  #works fine for 36*78
```

or you can use xargs

```
$ ls | xargs -n 3 #list files in three column
```